# Grails: Is there a way to run a filter after the view is completely, totally rendered?

Tags: grails

I have a filter that is currently defined to run after the view is rendered:

```
class MyFilter {
  def filters = {
    doStuff(controller: '*', action: '*') {
      before = {...}
      after = {...} 
      afterView = { 
        // code I want to run when EVERYTHING is set and done }
        Holder.setCurrentData(null)
    }
  }
}
```

This should work, but I noticed that `<g:message />` tags (and possibly others; this is the one what interests me at this point) are executed after the `afterView` filter.

This is a problem because I use this filter to keep track of some information for the current execution in a ThreadLocal, and I want to make sure I clean up after myself when the  request is done.  I don't want to use the request/session object to shuffle the data along, because then I have to pass it to all the calls I make; as it is, I have a Holder class that I can query for the value in the ThreadLocal.

I need the information from that ThreadLocal in my custom MessageSource.  That's how I noticed that `<g:message />` is called after the `afterView` filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a servlet filter:

```
package com.mycompany

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;

import org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean;

public class MyFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

   public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

      try {
         chain.doFilter(req, res);
      }
      finally {
         Holder.setCurrentData(null);   
      }
   }
}
```

Run `grails install-templates` if you haven't already and then you can register it in src/templates/war/web.xml like this:

```
<filter>
   <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>com.mycompany.MyFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I've extended `GenericFilterBean` for convenience but you could also just implement the `javax.servlet.Filter` interface directly. It could also be written in Groovy, but I tend to write filters in Java since they're called for every request, and the small overhead that Groovy adds can add up here.

Comment: This solution works correctly.  I'm disappointed that Grails doesn't have a better way of handling this; this feels like "rolling your own".  Do you know why the `afterView` filter doesn't run once the view is totally rendered, tags and all?

Comment: Grails filters wrap Spring `HandlerInterceptor`s, so they're limited to only intercepting controller requests and not static resource requests, and also only have the same callbacks as a `HandlerInterceptor`.

Comment: Thank you.  That explains it.